# BiometricManager to determine Face recognition result vs Fingerprint

Tags: android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I have started migrating to BiometricManager part of Android 29.
We have a requirement to display a different icon for face or Fingerprint depending upon device support. Even the following code returns true on Pixel 4 though Face recognition is available.

```
 PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
 pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)
```

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73321606/5790767) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The following [blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd) walks you through implementing the Biometrics Library. If you follow the instructions, then your app should work  with all form-factors without you having to do anything (whether fingerprint, face, iris, etc.).

Essentially, with the new library, UI is no longer the concern of developers. The library will detect whether a device uses face or fingerprint and will display the appropriate UI to the user.

You may also find [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html) useful.

Comment: This doesn't work. There is no way to differentiate  between fingerprint vs biometric